# java - How would I dynamically add swing component to gui on click?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

What I am looking to do is a similar principle to adding attachments to emails, you can click a button and a new browse box would open increasing the number of separate attachments you can have.

I'm fairly new so if someone could point me towards an example?

Comment: You can do it as you do it statically, but they may be nicer solutions depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sample code to add Buttons on the fly dynamically.

```
panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
validate();
```

Full code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class AddComponentOnJFrameAtRuntime extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panel;

    public AddComponentOnJFrameAtRuntime() {
        super("Add component on JFrame at runtime");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton("CLICK HERE");
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
        this.panel.revalidate();
        validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddComponentOnJFrameAtRuntime acojfar = new AddComponentOnJFrameAtRuntime();
    }
}
```

- [Resource](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/add-component-on-jframe-during-runtime.html)

Comment: As far as I know, `revalidate()` and/or `validate()` should be followed by `repaint()` (or changes wont be refelcted) also using `validate()` is redundant as `revalidate()` calls `validate()`

Comment: Calling `repaint()` after `validate()` or `revalidate()` is not always necessary. Though I do not know the conditions for when it is required... I have a case in my app where without `validate()`, `revalidate()`, and `repaint()` the window does not redraw when a component is added. Just adding `validate()` causes the new component to be displayed.

Comment: @jmj - Thanks  for the solution., actually its works when we dont have other task to perform inside `actionPerformed` method. But if i have some other task to perform, firstly its performing those task and at last moment `Button` is adding to the `panel`.  I was expecting in the reverse case. First it should add `Button` in the `Panel` and perform other task for that `actionperformed` method.

Answer (score 10):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Click to add") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    frame.add(new JLabel("Bla"));
                    frame.validate();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Component was not visible until `setSize()` was called:

```
component.setSize(100,200);
jPanel.add(component);
jPanel.revalidate();
jPanel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

panel.add(button);

panel.revalidate();

panel.repaint();

Answer (score 1):

> Java : Dynamically add swing components

```
for Example : count=3
//Java Swing: Add Component above method
public void  dya_addcomp(int count)
{
//Dynamicaly Delete Image_icon
 BufferedImage Drop_Tablefield = null;
 try {
     Drop_Tablefield = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/images/drop.png"));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     msg(" Error: drop and edit icon on Table, "+ex);
 }
 //count Items:  3 times for loop executed..
 for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
 {
     //cnt++;
     //lblcount.setText("Count : "+cnt);
     JTextField txtcolnm=new JTextField("",20);
     JComboBox cmbtype=new JComboBox();
     JTextField txtcolsize=new JTextField("",20);

     JButton Drop_Table_Field = new JButton(new ImageIcon(Drop_Tablefield));

     cmbtype.addItem("INTEGER"); cmbtype.addItem("FLOAT");
     cmbtype.addItem("STRING");  cmbtype.addItem("BOOLEAN");

     colnamepanel.add(txtcolnm);   colnamepanel.add(cmbtype);
     colnamepanel.add(txtcolsize); colnamepanel.add(Drop_Table_Field);

     colnamepanel.setAutoscrolls(true);

     //refresh panel
     colnamepanel.revalidate();
     colnamepanel.repaint();

     //set the layout on Jpanel
     colnamepanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5,0));
  }//end for loop
 }//end method
```