# Java Add an external class panel in the main Panel

Tags: java, swing, class, jpanel

i have a problem.

I want to have a Main Panel in which will load another panel that is inside a different class.

The main panel is this:

```
public class ClassPanel extends JPanel {

public ClassPanel(){
    JLabel scritta = new JLabel("Which Panel");
    JButton one = new JButton("Panel 1");


    class b1Button implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           GameOne gameone = new GameOne();
           add(gameone);
        }

    }

    one.addActionListener(new b1Button());

    add(scritta);
    add(one);

}}
```

And the class GameOne is this:

```
public class GameOne extends JPanel{

public GameOne() {
    JLabel lab = new JLabel("Game 1 selected");
    add(lab);
}}
```

The problem is that when i click the Button 1 in the main panel, i don't see the label in the GameOne class.

Whats the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure there are no compiler errors when compiling your project?

Comment: Yes there are no errors, or maybe Netbeans find no errors.

Comment: @SimoneBrigante Call the method `revalidate()` after the line containing `add(gameone)`

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode Thank you!! Now it works! :D

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click), might help !