# Add JPanel to on button click

Tags: java, swing, dynamic

kind of a newb so I couldn't quite get the other answers.

So I'm making a program where you keep track of exercise feedback. Every set of exercises has a different amount of exercises, so I can't put 10 fields and hope they're enough.

So I have a frame which contains scrollpane and a panel and in there are some general textfields concerning the coursework. Underneath I need to dynamically add panels according to the users whish. Any idea how to do this?

The general panel
[image: My window]

The panel I need to add dynamically to the empty space of the previous panel.
[image]

Comment: Give us some code to see.

Comment: @Arefe it's all generated from Netbeans Java Swing. What would you like to see?

Comment: Wow. That's almost like a [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) of tasks..

Answer (score 0):

you can create it and setVisibile() to false. Than when the user click or another action you set this panel to true :)
if you want to ADD it dinamamically , this is the question:[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click)

Comment: That wont work, because I can still create a set amount of fields. A coursework might have 5 or 50 questions, and it just isn't feasible.

In any case, this project is over, so