# Java repaint does not do anything

Tags: java, swing, repaint

Here is my problem:
I have a JPannel Order, in which I have different components; one JTable, and a few JLabel.

These components are filled with datas coming from an object "commande"(order)ex: idOrder, customer, Price...

This JPannel is inside an other Jpanel which contains also a jtable (orderlist)

When I click on an order in the jtable orderlist, I want the information about this order to be printed on the jpannel Order.

Now, I click, my object order is updated correctly but I cannot do the repaint() of the JPannel. Nothing happens.

Here is the code

```
   public class PanneauDetailCommande extends JPanel{
        Commande commande;
        PanneauDetailCommande(){}

        public void setCommande(Commande commande){this.commande=commande;}

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

          String colorPaye=commande.isPaye()? "GREEN" : "RED";

          this.setBackground(Color.white);

          this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

          this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));

          JLabel labelDetail=new JLabel("<html><p style=\"padding-left:15px;\"><font  size=4 > Détail commande<font color=\""+colorPaye+"\" size=4 > No  "+(commande.getIdCommande())+"</font> :</font></p></html>");

         labelDetail.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(598,20));

         labelDetail.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.black));

         labelDetail.setOpaque(true);

         labelDetail.setBackground(Color.white );

         this.add(labelDetail);

 }}
```

Another class JPannel which calls JPannel detailCommande:

```
 historique.table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new   ListSelectionListener(){

       @Override

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       int newId=Integer.parseInt(historique.table.getValueAt(historique.table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());

       Commande newCommande = gestionCommande.getCommande(newId);

       detail.setCommande(newCommande);

       detail.repaint();

       }});
```

Comment: Does not do nothing? Or does not do anything?

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Lol, i Mean "Nothing happens"

Comment: ok thank you @Massimo

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not add your components in the `paintComponent` method. You should instead adding them in event handlers, basically when you call `setCommande` and then calling revalidate on your component.

See answers and code in

[java - How would I dynamically add swing component to gui on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click)

Comment: ok, so i did a method drawPannel() where i have all the components, setCommande() calls drawPannel(), and do Revalidate(), but nothing happens : public void setCommande(Commande commande){
  this.commande=commande;
  this.drawPannel();
  this.revalidate();}
  
  /*pour commencer ,on affiche la dernière commande*/
 public void drawPannel(){
  /*le panneau*/
  this.setBackground(Color.white);.....ect....}

Answer (score 1):

ok, so i did put all my component in a method called drawPannel(),
my method setcommnade() calls drawPannel(), like this:

```
public void setCommande(Commande commande){
    this.commande=commande;
    this.drawPannel();
    }

    /*pour commencer ,on affiche la dernière commande*/
public void drawPannel(){
    /*le panneau*/
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    ...ect}
```

.then , in my actionListener, i tried invalidate();validate();repaint();revalidate();but nothing happens at all.

i tried to change background color of a component and then to system.out.print my component color to see if the change is done, and it works finebut i cannot refresh the screen.

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                    System.out.println(detail.getComponents()[0].getBackground());//java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
                    detail.getComponents()[0].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    System.out.println(detail.getComponents()[0].getBackground());//java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
                    //detail.setCommande(newCommande);
                    detail.invalidate();
                    detail.validate();
                    detail.repaint();
               }});
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, i have the answer if it can help somebody:

i do:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    detail.setCommande(newCommande);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
               }});
```

instead of :

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    detail.setCommande(newCommande);
                    detail.revalidate();
                    detail.repaint();
               }});
```

in conclusion , i repaint the entire main pannel and not the inside pannel the pannel